# rails 4.1 unable to get all enum types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just upgrade my app to rails 4.1.0.beta1

I have a class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum usertype: { :employee => 10, :boss => 30, :manager => 40, :admin => 50 }
}
```

All the enum feature works well like user.boss? # ture

But when I try to get all user types by

```
User.usertypes
```

I got a undefined method for "usertypes"

Any helps?

This is the link the I learn from http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Edit: 
migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :remember_token
      t.boolean :is_locked
      t.integer :usertype, default: 10
      t.timestamp :last_login_at

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you created the proper migrations?

Enum attributes are **values which map to integers** in the database, but can be queried by name.

So you'll need a migration which adds an integer column with the name 'usertype' to the Users table.  Have you done that?

**EDIT 1**:

Okay, just tested it out and the class method to get the mapping doesn't work with Rails 4.1.0.beta1, but does work with edge Rails.  So hopefully that gets pulled into the next beta release...

**EDIT 2**:

Also, check out [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b242b2dbe75f0b5e86e2ce9ef7c2c5ee96e17862) which demonstrates the way you'd access the enum mapping in Rails 4.1.0.beta1 using a constant instead of a class method.  So in your case you'd use `User::USERTYPE` to access your mapping.

Comment: For an User instance does the enum work? e.g. `User.find(1).usertype`?

Comment: Okay, see the edit in the answer. Worked with edge Rails, but not 4.1.0.beta1

Comment: Thank you! That is how I do enum in rails 4.